# Pdf desktop icons

Tags: macos, operating-systems

I've read the many topics sort of like mine, but they don't fix my problem.  I keep getting a tiny width icon when creating a pdf in the finder.  If I go command-J it will adjust ALL icons on desktop but not a specific one, and new pdf's still produce the tiny width icon.  Suggestions please!

Comment: You should include a picture, including the other desktop icons.  Also, what application is the default app to open PDF files?  Default is "Preview", but if you've changed that, that could affect this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click on a blank area of the desktop and select "Show View Options"  Then you can adjust the icon size and spacing for the desktop.  Additional options are also available such as how the icons should be sorted, etc are also available.